# Sir Trevor letter counter

Tags: javascript, sirtrevor

I'm using SirTrevorJs (http://madebymany.github.io/sir-trevor-js) and I would like to add a letter counter on each SirTrevor.

Currently I can't even detect a focus on the SirTrevor. If anyone did it before I appreciate an explanation.

```
var $st = $('[data-type="sirtrevor"]');
$st.on('focusin', function() {
    console.log('ok');
});
```

Thanks and have a nice day!

**Edit:**

Thanks to D. Cantatore for the focusin!
There is a complete code working!

```
var $st = $('.st-ready');

$.each($st, function() {
  var $self = $(this);

  $self.on('focusin', function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    var $textBlock = $this.find('.st-text-block');

    $this.on('keyup', function() {
      var i = 0;
      $.each($textBlock, function() {
        i += $(this).text().length;
      });
      console.log('There is ' + i + ' letters in the SirTrevor');
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: can you setup a jsfiddle? I tried setting one up fast but there is a bit of configuration I don't fully know

Comment: I can't really setup one cause of the external ressources but there is an example here : http://madebymany.github.io/sir-trevor-js/example.html

Comment: You can find it on copen http://codepen.io/victor-gabou/pen/bZXGXo

Comment: Does it need to be focusin event? Why not use hover or click? I'm adding an answer with a fork that I laid out some ground work to make function as your are looking.

Comment: Did my answer help?

Answer (score 0):

I added the functionality you are looking for by adding the focusin element to the class of the text box. Also added a counter but you'll need to work out how to bind it to each text box.

http://codepen.io/dcantatore/pen/BzXNPX

```
var i = 0
$('.st-ready').focusin(function() {
$(this).keyup(function(e) {
  i++;  
  console.log(i) 
})
});
```

Comment: Ok, thanks for the focusin event working, I'll continue to work on the letter counter on my side!